# How do I spawn a block under an armor stand in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a parkour course that generates itself as you jump. However, I don't know how to make the block spawn.

I already made an armor stand follow me with this command:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] Sieniz 
                                  (my name)
```

but how do I make the block spawn under me? I know how I could do it but I don't know how should the commands go. Can somebody help?

I am trying to do it in version 1.16.4.

Answer (score 2):

```
 /execute at @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=joe] run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:dark_prismarine
```

You can skip the entire armorstand shenanigans and address `@p` (the player) instead.

Comment: i does nothing :/ are you sure this works on 1.16.4?

Comment: @JoelMyllyvirta What are you doing exactly?